# Searching through tuple of more than 2 elements

Tags: haskell

How can I search a tuple based on the first element or second or third?

I know how to search tuple of two but how do i do it for more than two?

```
type Stuff = (String, String, Int)

testStuff :: [Stuff]
testStuff = [
    ("beans","black",5),
    ("cod","fish",4),
    ("coke","diet",3)
]
```

How can I write a function that will search "Stuff" and return the "int" value?

e.g  searchStuff "beans" should return 5.

Comment: Well... what have you tried so far? What's your solution for finding it when you only have pairs? You'll find there isn't so much of a difference between the two cases.

Comment: The same, filter + pattern matching

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you haven't provided your function for searching in a list of pairs, I'm going to assume that you used [`lookup`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=lookup). Lets focus on `find` for your new function. `find` can be found in [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:find) (and a more general version in [`Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:find)) and has the following type:

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
```

Now, if you need to find something in a list of triples based on the first element, you could use

```
find (\(a,_,_) -> a == "beans") testStuff
```

However, this will leave you with a `Maybe Stuff`. But since `Maybe` is an instance of `Functor`, it is easy to change the result to `Maybe Int` (and is left as an exercise).

Answer (score 2):

[The Prelude defines `lookup` to handle searching a list of pairs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup). Here's the definition:

```
-- | 'lookup' @key assocs@ looks up a key in an association list.
lookup                  :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
lookup _key []          =  Nothing
lookup  key ((x,y):xys)
    | key == x          =  Just y
    | otherwise         =  lookup key xys
```

Can you see how one would define a similar function to search a list of triples?